# App crash with this error in some device..java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

My application running in all device except some samsung device..
These device give exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
```

I am using this dependency -

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Comment: before down vote leave a comment here or post a reason..

Comment: Please check in your device, Google Play Service installed or not.

Comment: @KundanKumarRoy Are you using map in your application or not?

Comment: @Dhruv yes I am using

Comment: @KundanKumarRoy Can you please share some code which is relevant for the same.

Comment: are you using proGuard ? Maybe proguard removes some classes when you build. Add the classes to -keep in your proguards settings or just turnoff proguard and try to compile.

Answer (score 4):

I got solution its not about play service. it was multidex error in pre lollipop devices.

added mutidex dependency in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

According to that [site](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html),
You need to add the following `@Override` method to the class that extends `Application`:

```
public class FirebaseCntx extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {

        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Samsung tab 4.4.2 device. The issue is not because of the google play services. It is because of the multidex support enabled in Gradle script but forgot to update the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

It is resolved after adding **android:name** into manifest file.